# All possible permutations of all possible sizes in java

Tags: java, algorithm, vector

Say I have the numbers 1, 2 ,3. What would the algorithm look like in order to take all the possible permutations of that in all possible sizes. The output:

`1, 2 ,3 | 3, 2 ,1  | 2, 1 ,3 | 1, 3, 2 ... | 1, 2 | 2, 1 | 3, 1 |..... 1 | 2 | 3`

Would you just do the normal permutations algorithm and input each amount of letters as a sub problem?

Comment: Please tag this as homework if that's what it is, then try it yourself and show us what you've tried.  There are several ways to write the algorithm, depending on whether you prefer loops or recursion.  Your suggestion to break it into recursive sub-problems is a good start.

Comment: Im sorry but this is not Homework. I was trying to solve a contest question and I realized that the basic premise of it was this however was clueless on how to solve it.

Comment: You should still take a crack at it and ask for help where you are stuck. IMHO the point of a contest question isn't to find the answers on Stackoverflow, and the point of Stackoverflow isn't to answer contest questions for people.

Comment: No apology necessary, and though I'd hope the downvoters would explain their reasons I suspect it's because your question doesn't show that you've put your own effort into solving the problem--that goes a long way toward making people want to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate all possible subsets and permute them.

Pseudo code (follows C++)

```
generate (a[]) {
    int size = a.size;
    sort(a)
    for (i = 1; i < (1<<size); i++) {
        b[];
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            if (i&(1<<j)) {
                add a[j] to b;
            }
        }

        do {
            for (i=0 to b.size) {
                print b[i];
            }
        }while(next_permutation(b.begin(), b.end());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you sort `a` once . There's no need to sort `b` repeatedly.